# Is there a mocking framework that allows me to define new default behavior?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

In our tests, we have mock objects which have just slightly different behavior. It would be nice to be able to override default behavior with new default behavior, so we would only have to define the explicitly different behavior on a per-test basis. We're currently using unitils, but we're looking for a solution to the problem in any java mocking framework.

Illustration of the problem (using unitils):

```
Mock<MyClass> myMock1 = new MockObject<>(MyClass.class,myTestedObject);
myMock1.returns(1).getAnInteger();
myMock1.returns("Hello").getAString();
myMock1.returns(true).getABoolean();
myMock1.returns(3.14).getADouble();

Mock<MyClass> myMock2 = new MockObject<>(MyClass.class,myTestedObject);
myMock2.returns(2).getAnInteger();
myMock2.returns("Hello").getAString();
myMock2.returns(false).getABoolean();
myMock2.returns(3.14).getADouble();
```

What we're looking for could be something like this:

```
MockObjectFactory<MyClass> myMockObjectFactory = new MockObjectFactory<>(MyClass.class);
myMockObjectFactory.defaultReturns(1).getAnInteger();
myMockObjectFactory.defaultReturns("Hello").getAString();
myMockObjectFactory.defaultReturns(false).getABoolean();
myMockObjectFactory.defaultReturns(3.14).getADouble();

Mock<MyClass> myMock1 = myMockObjectFactory.createMockObject(myTestedObject);
myMock1.returns(true).getABoolean();

Mock<MyClass> myMock2 = myMockObjectFactory.createMockObject(myTestedObject);
myMock2.returns(2).getAnInteger();
```

Do you know any current java mocking framework that supports overriding default behavior with new default behavior?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, it looks like you are trying to do something very simple, the two major mocking frameworks are Mockito and EasyMock, I haven heard of this unitils before.

Comment: Many mocking frameworks have default behavior for mocked objects, like getters returning 0/false/null unless the behavior is overridden. I want my getters to return something else unless overridden.This is a very simplified example. Imagine if there were a dozen methods, and the individual mocks need only override a couple of them - then the benefit would be much bigger.

Comment: this looks like basic mocking functionality to me... stubbing a method is exactly what you are describing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at so called  [spies of mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) or [dynamic (partial) mocking](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#dynamicPartial) of JMockit

Comment: This is interesting. So, I create an object with my default behavior and override only parts of its behavior - that sounds like a solution.

Comment: As it turns out, even unitils supports partial mocking, so our problem is solved :) Thanks!